# AddSiteAccount & GetSiteRefreshInfo

Tags: yodlee

Upon calling AddSiteAccount1 on the REST API, I understand that a code of 801 means refresh in progress, and I should call GetSiteRefreshInfo until it has finished refreshing.

I have a few questions around this process.

1) Is the SiteAccountId returned from AddSiteAccount1 the MemSiteAccountId required by GetSiteRefreshInfo? If so, it would be nice if the docs said this, or that the two fields were named the same. If not, to get MemSiteAccountId, do I need to call GetItemSummaries? If so how do I match the accounts to get the correct MemSiteAccountId

2) My personal bank account (at ASB in New Zealand, site 4330) does not use MFA during the login, however the response from AddSiteAccount1 has the SiteRefreshInfo.RefreshMode == 'MFA'. This appears to be an error with the sandbox data? Or am I reading the response wrong? I tested my accounts in MoneyCenter and they didn't seem to think it was an MFA account. Could this be a data error in the sandbox environment?

This is the refresh info associated with this site:

```
"refreshInfo": {
  "itemId": 10023028,
  "statusCode": 0,
  "refreshType": 2,
  "refreshRequestTime": 0,
  "lastUpdatedTime": 1396922296,
  "lastUpdateAttemptTime": 1396922296,
  "itemAccessStatus": {
    "name": "ACCESS_VERIFIED"
  },
  "userActionRequiredType": {
    "name": "NONE"
  },
  "userActionRequiredCode": 0,
  "lastDataUpdateAttempt": {
    "date": "2014-04-07T18:58:16-0700",
    "status": {
      "name": "SUCCESS"
    },
    "statusCode": 0,
    "type": {
      "name": "USER_REQUESTED"
    }
  },
  "lastUserRequestedDataUpdateAttempt": {
    "date": "2014-04-07T18:58:16-0700",
    "status": {
      "name": "SUCCESS"
    },
    "statusCode": 0,
    "type": {
      "name": "USER_REQUESTED"
    }
  },
  "lastSuccessfulDataUpdate": "2014-04-07T18:58:16-0700",
  "itemCreateDate": "2014-04-07T18:58:16-0700",
  "nextUpdateTime": 1397511763,
  "responseCodeType": {
    "responseCodeTypeId": 1
  },
  "retryCount": 0,
  "refreshMode": "MFA"
},
```

3) Are there any accounts in the sandbox environment that use MFA so that we are able to test our MFA integration?

Answer (score 0):

@Chris

Here are the answers:

1. Yes both of them are same i.e. siteAccountId= MemSiteAccountId.
   We will take this point into consideration and will get it corrected over the portal.
2. This is not an error with Sandbox environment/data. This site has been mentioned as MFA because this site supports NetCode Token which is an opt in feature available at the bank website. You might have not registered for the same and this is why you don't need to enter any MFA related information in your login process.
3. Yodlee provides a tool known as [DAG(Dummy Account Generator)](https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Indy_FinApp_Knowledgebase/Sample_Data/Yodlee_Dummy_Account_Generator) this should suffice your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. 
Regarding number 2, you are correct, I forgot you can set netcode at sign on. How do I determine whether a particular user needs to enter the Netcode at sign on versus one that doesn't?

Comment: @Chris- Please check this [link](http://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/getMFAResponseForSite). This have the required information and flow.